# Why isn't it necessary to postulate the existence of $1$?

Tags: natural-numbers, peano-axioms

[These](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeanosAxioms.html) are the Peano axioms, I'll focus on the second one now:

> If $a$ is a number, the successor of $a$ is a number.

Basically, here is defined the [successor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successor_function) $S(n)=n+1$. My question is, how doesn't $S(n)$ depend on the existence of $1$? To get from $0$ to $1$ we need to have a sum, and a sum is between two or more numbers. So, since we are summing $0$ and $1$ to get $1$, aren't we *already assuming* that $1$ is a number? I've been thinking about it for some time, thanks in advance for clarification.

Comment: No, the successor function exists on its own, by assumption. The sum then defined recursively (thanks to the induction axiom) with regards to its properties on the successor function. In fact it says so in the link you posted: `As such, it is not defined by addition, but rather is used to define all natural numbers beyond 0, as well as addition`.

Comment: 1 is defined in terms of the succesor function (as the successor of 0), as well as the operation of addition, not the other way around

Comment: $\operatorname S(x)=\begin{cases}\operatorname 1+S(x-1),&x\ge1\\S(x+1)-1,&x<0\\1,&x=0\end{cases}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We don’t need a sum in order to postulate the existence of a successor function. In fact, we use the successor function to *define* addition: the successor function comes first.

You’re confusing the successor function as a primitive entity whose properties are determined by the axioms with its intended interpretation, which is indeed that $S(n)=n+1$. The intended interpretation is a large part of the reason for the choice of axioms defining the characteristics of the successor function, but the successor function itself is defined by those axioms, not by the interpretation that inspired them.

Comment: So in fact $S(0):=1$, right? I understand what you and the others said, but that $+1$ would still make me think. To sum up, $S(0):=1,S(1)=1+1=2,\ldots$ or am I missing something?

Comment: @Vincenzo: You have it backwards: $1:=S(0)$, $2:=S(S(0))=S(1)$, etc. The successor function is basic: everything else is defined in terms of it and $0$.

Comment: Yes, I see. Thanks again, Brian!

Comment: @Vincenzo: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Numbers in this context would be taken to be whatever satisfies the axioms.  So you have the first one, then its successor, then the successor of that, and so on.  No operation of *addition* is defined in advance on this set.  Rather, that comes later: one uses the sequence of numbers and the successor function to say what addition is.  The successor function is not in this context defined as $x\mapsto x+1$.  It is merely a function satisfying the axioms.